# Identify a bird by its feather

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Gray feather with red tip, about 5 cm (2 in) total length. It was found in Lexington, Kentucky (central western USA).

[image: Gray feather with red tip, about 2" total length]

Comment: Where did you find it (which type of ecosystem and what country / region)?

Comment: Good point. Sorry, I'm not used to posting here. But I think the answer is below. I'll try to give better information in the future.

Comment: @vknowles That's nice, thanks, but please tell us the location, so I can edit your question (making it complete for future reference).

Comment: It was in our back yard in Lexington, KY

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to be the [secondary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_feather#secondaries) feather of a [Waxwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waxwing), a bird from the Genus *Bombycilla*, like *Bombycilla cedrorum*:

[image]

<sup>Cedar waxwing. Source: https://rctfan2.deviantart.com/art/Cedar-Waxwing-285656802</sup>

Actually, that red tip gives the bird its name (from the Wikipedia link):

> They have unique red tips to some of the wing feathers where the shafts extend beyond the barbs; in the Bohemian and Cedar waxwings, these tips look like [sealing wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealing_wax), and give the group its common name.

Therefore, the possible species are the [Bohemian waxwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohemian_waxwing) (*B. garrulus*)...

[image]

... and the [Cedar waxwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedar_waxwing) (*B. cedrorum*):

[image]

However, since the secondaries of *B. garrulus* normally have a white area next to the tip...

[image]

... I'd guess that your feather belongs to *B. cedrorum*.

#### In conclusion

Besides the white patches in the feathers of Bohemian waxwings, OP [just confirmed](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/68276/identify-a-bird-by-its-feather#comment123295_68288) that the range of the Bohemian waxwing doesn't match. Therefore, this feather belongs indeed to a **Cedar waxwing**.

Comment: I think it is the Cedar waxwing because after reading about the range, it seems unlikely to be the Bohemian. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I’m impressed.